# how to access javascript variables in python

Tags: javascript, python

I am creating a facebook app and it uses Javascript API to store username and other details in js variables. And this app is created under Python(using Google App Engine). I want to access the js variables in Python and store the values in Db. How to do this?

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("""
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
      <title>Captain Pandey</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '185318768251247',
            channelURL : 'http://localhost:8080/channel.html',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });



         FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/me', function(apiResponse) {
              var name = apiResponse.name;
            });
          } 
          else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
          }
          else {
          // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
          }
       });

        };

        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1" scope="email">Login to Facebook</div>
    </body>
 </html>
    """)
```

and template used is webapp2

Comment: JS variables, as you know, exist on the client side, Python code exists on the server side. The only way to communicate for them is using HTTP (e.g. AJAX). No direct access.

Comment: It would help to mark up the code to show which variables in the Javascript you want to store, and at what point, with what controlling logic.

Answer (score 4):

Design the Javascript code so that it makes an AJAX request that sends the data, and write a Python handler for that request.